# How to use prxmatch or alternative for below string in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have multiple rows of strings

```
Eg 1.
Our commission is 25% for next order
Eg2.
20% is applied for previous order
```

I want remove and create new column with  25% and 20% and so on... From above string.

How can I do that in SAS? The new column should flow 25% i.e percentage.

```
ColA.                                     ColB
Our commission is 25% for next order.     25%
20% is applied for previous order.        20%
.
.
.
```

So on....

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How you handle such lines as "For next order we increase our order by 10% from 20% to 30%" or "For next order we decrease or order by 10% to 20% from 30%"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single percentage value (or none) can be retrieved from a string using a pattern with a grouping expression `(<something>)`, `prxmatch`, and `prxposn` to retrieve the characters matching the grouped expression.

Example:

The percentage is presumed to be a whole number followed immediately by a percent sign.

Store the percentage as a fraction (presumed to be in 0 to 1 range) whose value is formatted for display as a percentage.

```
data have;
  input;
  line = _infile_;
datalines;
Eg 1.
Our commission is 25% for next order
Eg2.
20% is applied for previous order
run;

data want;
  set have;

  /* pattern for finding and capturing a whole number that is followed by a percent sign */
  rx = prxparse('/(\d+)%/');

  if prxmatch(rx,line) then do;
    matched_digits = prxposn(rx, 1, line);
    fraction = input(matched_digits, 12.) / 100;
  end;

  format fraction percent5.;
run;
```